# meshlab- how to transfer uvs from source .objs onto poisson reconstruction model

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I've been struggling for some time to find a way in Meshlab to include or transfer UV’s onto a poisson model from source meshes. I will try to explain more of what I’m trying to accomplish below.

My source meshes have uv’s along with texture data. I need to build a fused model and include the texture data. It is for facial expression scan data reconstruction for a production pipeline which ultimately builds a facial rig for animation. Our source scan data includes marker information which we use to register, build a fused scan model which is used to generate a retopologized mesh for blendshapes.

Previously, we were using David3D. http://www.david-3d.com/en/support/downloads
 David 3D used poisson surface reconstruction to create a fused model. The fused model it created brought along the uvs and optimized the source textures into 1 uv tile. I'll post a picture of the result below that I'm looking to recreate in MeshLab.

My need to find this solution in meshlab is to build tools to help automate this process. David3D version 5 does not have an development kit to program around.

Is it possible in Meshlab to apply the uvs from the regions used from the source mesh onto the poison model? Could I use a filter to transfer them? Reproject them?

Or is there another reconstruction method/ process from within Meshlab that will keep the uv’s?

Here is an image of what the resulting uv parameter looks like from David. The uvs are white on the left half of the image.

Thank You,[David3D UV Layout Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj3Hb.jpg)

Dan

Comment: you need to narrow down your question or include code samples form your own attempts at solving this

Comment: Serg, I'm asking if its possible to transfer uv information from source to target mesh using MeshLab, and which filter and order of operation I need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

No, in MeshLab there is no direct way to transfer UV mapping between two layers.
This is because UV transfer is not, in the general case, a trivial task. It is not simply a matter of assigning to the new surface the "closest" UV of the original mesh: this would not work on UV discontinuities, which are present in the example you linked. Additionally, the two meshes should be almost coincident, otherwise you would also have problems also in defining the "closest" UV.

There are a couple ways to do it, but require manual work and a re-sampling of the texture:

- create a UV mapping of the re-meshed model using whatever tool you may have, then resample the existing texture on the new parametrization using "transfer: vertex attributes to Texture (1 or 2 meshes)", using texture color as source
- load the original mesh, and using the screenshot function, create "virtual" photos of the model (turn off illumination and do NOT use ortho views), adding them as raster layers, until the model surface has been fully covered. Load the new model, that should be in the same space, and texture-map it using the "parametrization + texturing " using those registered images

In MeshLab it is also possible to create a new texture from the original images, if you have a way to import the registered cameras...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** UV coords to color channels → Vertex Attribute Transfer → Color channels back to UV coords

---

I have had very good results kludging it through the color channels, like this (say you are transfering from layer A to layer B):

1. Make sure A and B are roughly aligned with eachother (you can use the ICP filter if needed).
2. Select layer A, then:

   1. *Texture → Convert Per Wedge UV to Per Vertex UV* (if you've got wedge coords)
   2. *Color Creation → Per Vertex Color Function*, and transfer the tex coords to the color channels (assuming UV range 0-1, you'll want to tweak these if your range is larger):

      - func r = 255.0 * vtu
      - func g = 255.0 * vtv
      - func b = 0
3. *Sampling → Vertex Attribute Transfer*, and use this to transfer the vertex colors (which now hold texture coordinates) from layer A to layer B.

   - source mesh = layer A
   - target mesh = layer B
   - check Transfer Color
   - set distance large enough to not miss any spots
4. Now select layer B, which contains the mapped vertex colors, and do the opposite that you did for A:

   1. *Texture → Per Vertex Texture Function*

      - func u = r / 255.0
      - func v = g / 255.0
   2. *Texture → Convert Per Vertex UV to Per Wedge UV*

And that's it.

The results aren't going to be perfect, but in practice I often find them sufficient. In particular:

- If the texture is not continuously mapped to layer A (e.g. maybe you've got patches of image mapped to certain areas, etc.), it's very possible for the attribute transfer to B (especially when upsampling) to have some vertices be interpolated across patch boundaries, which will probably lead to visual artifacts along patch boundaries.
- UV coords may be quantized by conversion to a color channel and back. (You could maybe eliminate this by stretching U out over all three color channels, then transferring U, then repeating for V -- never tried it though.)

That said, there's a lot of cases it works in.

I may or may not add images / video to this post another day.

PS Meshlab is pretty straightforward to build from source; it might be possible to add a UV coordinate option to the Vertex Attribute Transfer filter. But, to make it more useful, you'd want to make sure that you didn't interpolate across boundary edges in the mapped UV projection. Definitely a project I'd like to work on some day... in theory. If that ever happens I'll post a link here.